# webException status property if error then print error else success

Tags: c#, .net

I have go through this code

```
  try {
```

// Create a web request for an invalid site. Substitute the "invalid site"           strong in the Create call with a invalid name.

```
       HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("invalid site");
```

// Get the associated response for the above request.

```
       HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse) myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
   myHttpWebResponse.Close();
 }
  catch(WebException e) {
Console.WriteLine("This program is expected to throw WebException on successful run."+"\n\nException Message :" + e.Message);
if(e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError) {
    Console.WriteLine("Status Code : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode);
    Console.WriteLine("Status Description : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription);
}
}
  catch(Exception e) {
Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you ask or what the problem is. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I want to throw exception from catch according to status number like 404, 501 etc and if it 200 status then successful massage

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question and comment I assume you're looking for something like this:

```
try
{
    HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://httpstat.us/500");
    using (HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        myHttpWebResponse.Close();
        int code = (int)myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode;
        if (code == 200)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("success");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("success with code {0}", code);
        }
    }
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
    {
        // protocol errors find the statuscode in the Response
        // the enum statuscode can be cast to an int.
        int code = (int) ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode;
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Status code {0} ", code)); 
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

You can catch an exception, inspect or transform the values provided by it and throw a new exception.

You didn't provide a lot of context but let me warn you that throwing exceptions to handle common business logic is not a best practice. You better refactor to a design where you return a status code so that callers of your code can use that instead of having to implement a try/catch. [Read this msdn document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173163.aspx) for more guidance, as well as the blogs on the topic from [Eric Lippert](http://ericlippert.com/category/exception-handling/).